# Go lang type assertion

Tags: go, type-assertion

I am trying to do dependency injection in golang with applying dependency inversion principle, so I have the following service

```golang
package account

import (
    types "zaClouds/modules/account/domain/types"
    "zaClouds/modules/shared"
)

type IPlanDomainService interface {
    GetUsagePlanById(string) *shared.Result[types.UsagePlan]
}

type PlanDomainService struct {
    usagePlanService types.IUsagePlanService
}

func (planDomainService *PlanDomainService) GetUsagePlanById(id string) *shared.Result[types.UsagePlan] {
    result := &shared.Result[types.UsagePlan]{}
    usagePlanResult := planDomainService.usagePlanService.GetPlanById(id)

    if usagePlanResult.Err != nil {
        result.Err = usagePlanResult.Err
        return result
    }
    result.Data = usagePlanResult.Data
    return result
}

func PlanDomainServiceFactory(usagePlanService types.IUsagePlanService) IPlanDomainService {
    return &PlanDomainService{usagePlanService: usagePlanService}
}
```

as you can see, it accepts another service with type `IUsagePlanService`

and here is the interface for it

```golang
package account

import (
    "zaClouds/modules/shared"

    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
)

type UsagePlan struct {
    ID          string
    Title       string
    Description interface{}
    PlanID      string
    Price       decimal.Decimal
    Duration    int
    Features    map[string]map[string]string
}
type IUsagePlanService interface {
    GetPlanById(string) *shared.Result[UsagePlan]
}
```

and here is the way I am injecting this service to domain service

```golang
func DiInit(usagePlanService interface{}) domainServices.IPlanDomainService {
domainServices.PlanDomainServiceFactory(types.IUsagePlanService(usagePlanService))
    return domainServices.PlanDomainServiceFactory(usagePlanService.(types.IUsagePlanService))
}
```

as you can see, I am trying to do a type assertion but it doesn't work, and gives me the following error:

```golang
panic: interface conversion: *usagePlan.UsagePlanRepository is not account.IUsagePlanService: missing method GetPlanById
```

##### Edit

Here is the actual implementation for usagePlanService

```golang
type IUsagePlanRepository interface {
    createClient(string) *http.Request
    GetPlanById(string) *shared.Result[usagePlanRepoModels.UsagePlan]
}

type UsagePlanRepository struct {
    plansEndpoint string
    httpClient    *http.Client
}

func (r *UsagePlanRepository) GetPlanById(id string) *shared.Result[usagePlanRepoModels.UsagePlan] {
    result := &shared.Result[usagePlanRepoModels.UsagePlan]{}

    req := r.createClient(id)
    resp, err := r.httpClient.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("failed to load plan details \n[ERROR]", err)
        result.Err = err
        return result
    }

    defer func() {
        bodyError := resp.Body.Close()

        if bodyError != nil {
            result.Err = bodyError
        }

    }()

    if result.Err != nil {
        return result
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        utils.Logger.Error("failed to load plan details \n[ERROR]", err, nil)
        result.Err = err
        return result
    }

    if resp.StatusCode >= 400 {
        result.Err = errors.New(string(body))
        utils.Logger.Info("getPlanById", string(body))
    }

    getUsagePlanResponse, foundError := usagePlanRepoModels.CreateGetUsagePlanResponse(body)

    if foundError != nil {
        result.Err = foundError
        return result
    }

    result.Data = *getUsagePlanResponse
    return result

}
```

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `GetPlanById` to your question?

Comment: `DiInit(usagePlanService interface{})` should be taking a defined interface type, not an empty interface.

Comment: @Adrian thank you for your comment, but I tried this, it doesn't solve the problem, it still need type conversion

Answer (score 0):

When using an interface, you need to define all functions that you will use with the same name and signature as the implementation.

The error message you got indicates that the implementation and the interface are different.

The implementation is not shown in your question, but you defined the function for your interface like this: `GetPlanById(string) *shared.Result[UsagePlan]`. Any deviation from it will result in error. One common mistake is with the pointers. Adding or removing the `*` to the return type will incur in error if it differs from the original.

Edit:

Your interface should look like this:

```
type IUsagePlanService interface {
    GetPlanById(id string) *shared.Result[usagePlanRepoModels.UsagePlan]
}
```

If your function is returning a private type, and you can change that, you should. If you cant change it, than you should create a function that wraps the function you are trying to abstract with the interface.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have added the actual implementation for `getPlanById` can you plz see it and tell me where is error?

Comment: another question

If I have `getPlanById` in the interface returns specific struct type, and `getPlanById` in the actual implementation returns another struct but with the same fields, is it will work or not?

Comment: @tareksalem To implement an interface the methods MUST match word-for-word. i.e. The name of the method MUST be the same, the input parameter types MUST be identical, the output parameter types MUST be identical.

Comment: @mkopriva can you please guide me how to solve the mentioned issue in the post

Comment: @tareksalem I've updated my answer. It looks like the return type of your function is in a private module. This is most likely a bad idea.
Check these links about this:
https://www.willhaley.com/blog/private-and-public-visibility-with-go-packages/
https://www.anycodings.com/1questions/4989312/golang-public-method-to-private-struct-is-this-have-any-use-case